# Determine / discover Kerberos realm, KDC host and KDC port on Windows 7

Tags: windows, authentication, ldap, kerberos

I am trying to authenticate against Kerberos using Apache Directory Studio from a Windows 7 machine.

Is there a way to discover or determine the Kerberos realm, KDC host and KDC port for the connection needed for authentication in Windows 7?

The Windows 7 machine I am using uses Kerberos to authenticate my Windows session - that is, Kerberos authentication is required in order to log into the Windows Domain so I guess that all the information required must be somewhere on my Windows 7 system except that I don't know how.

I hope my desciption doesn't sound too confusing. I tried to make it as clear as I can.

Comment: Try: https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/How%20Domain%20Controllers%20Are%20Located%20in%20Windows

Comment: I used klist to get my user name and Kerberos realm. Port is obviously the default port 88. host seems to be the same as the domaincontroller. Maybe there is a better way to get this information but now I have what I need.

Comment: You can query DNS: nslookup -type=any _kerberos._tcp and get most of the information you need. (If no looking for current machine realm use nslookup -type=any _kerberos._tcp.<yourdomain>.net )

Comment: @Arquebus - Please make your comment as an answer and accept it.  You are allowed to do this on a self-solved answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
nslookup -type=srv _kerberos._tcp.YOUR-DOMAIN

Ex: nslookup -type=srv _kerberos._tcp.EXAMPLE.COM
```